# Join multiple tables with same structure but different data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2005, view

I'm trying to make a join between 8 tables and because each of table has more than 500,000 entries, it is very slow. I want to know that, do you have any best way to join these tables?

All tables has this structure:

data_temprature:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID_geo | NAME     | Value | Date            |
+--------+----------+-------+-----------------+
|  10005 | Madrid   |  32   | 2017-06-12 08:00|
|  10005 | Madrid   |  25   | 2017-06-12 09:00|
|  12701 | Paris    |  23   | 2017-06-12 08:00|
|  13006 | Tokyo    |  25   | 2017-06-12 11:00|
|  11132 | Sevilla  |  27   | 2017-06-12 16:00|
|  21333 | London   |  22   | 2017-06-12 17:00|
+--------+----------+-------+-----------------+
```

data_WeatherSimbol

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID_geo | NAME     | Value | Date            |
+--------+----------+-------+-----------------+
|  10005 | Madrid   |  A+   | 2017-06-12 08:00|
|  10005 | Madrid   |  A    | 2017-06-12 09:00|
|  12701 | Paris    |  A-   | 2017-06-12 08:00|
|  13006 | Tokyo    |  C-   | 2017-06-12 11:00|
|  11132 | Sevilla  |  I+   | 2017-06-12 16:00|
|  21333 | London   |  D-   | 2017-06-12 17:00|
+--------+----------+-------+-----------------+
```

I wanna make a join to get this result:

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| ID_geo | NAME     | Temperature | Simboles |      Date       |
+--------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
|  10005 | Madrid   |      32     |    A+    | 2017-06-12 08:00|
|  10005 | Madrid   |      25     |    A     | 2017-06-12 09:00|
|  12701 | Paris    |      23     |    A-    | 2017-06-12 08:00|
|  13006 | Tokyo    |      25     |    C-    | 2017-06-12 11:00|
|  11132 | Sevilla  |      27     |    I+    | 2017-06-12 16:00|
|  21333 | London   |      22     |    D-    | 2017-06-12 17:00|
+--------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------------+
```

Thanks

**UPDATE REAL DATA PROVIDING:**

The EXECUTION PLAN:
https://files.fm/u/b4besk27

this is the query:

```
    SELECT
    cielo.data_value AS cielo,
    lluv.data_value AS lluvia,
  temp.data_value AS temp,
  vientos.data_value AS viento,
  tmin.data_value AS tempmin,
  tmax.data_value AS tempmax, 
    cielo.data_date AS DiaPrev
FROM
    data_cielo AS cielo
INNER JOIN data_lluvia AS lluv ON cielo.data_geo = lluv.data_geo
INNER JOIN data_presion AS pres ON cielo.data_geo = pres.data_geo
INNER JOIN data_temp AS temp ON cielo.data_geo = temp.data_geo
LEFT JOIN data_tempmax AS tmax ON cielo.data_geo = tmax.data_geo
LEFT JOIN data_tempmin AS tmin ON cielo.data_geo = tmin.data_geo
INNER JOIN data_viento AS vientos ON cielo.data_geo = vientos.data_geo

WHERE
    cielo.data_date = lluv.data_date
AND pres.data_date = cielo.data_date
AND vientos.data_date = pres.data_date
AND temp.data_date = vientos.data_date
AND cielo.data_geo = 46 ORDER BY cielo.data_date;
and this is the result:
```

---

```
E+  0.0461028   29.6937088  S2  19.408  36.39   2017-06-13 12:00:00.000
E+  0.0461028   29.6937088  S2  21.422  36.39   2017-06-13 12:00:00.000
E+  0.0461028   29.6937088  S2  19.408  37.853  2017-06-13 12:00:00.000
E+  0.0461028   29.6937088  S2  21.422  37.853  2017-06-13 12:00:00.000
E+  0.0461028   30.7593854  S2  19.408  36.39   2017-06-13 13:00:00.000
E+  0.0461028   30.7593854  S2  21.422  36.39   2017-06-13 13:00:00.000
E+  0.0461028   30.7593854  S2  19.408  37.853  2017-06-13 13:00:00.000
E+  0.0461028   30.7593854  S2  21.422  37.853  2017-06-13 13:00:00.000
A+  0.0461028   31.6310774  SSW2    19.408  36.39   2017-06-13 14:00:00.000
A+  0.0461028   31.6310774  SSW2    21.422  36.39   2017-06-13 14:00:00.000
A+  0.0461028   31.6310774  SSW2    19.408  37.853  2017-06-13 14:00:00.000
A+  0.0461028   31.6310774  SSW2    21.422  37.853  2017-06-13 14:00:00.000
A   0.0461028   32.2647927  S2  19.408  36.39   2017-06-13 15:00:00.000
A   0.0461028   32.2647927  S2  21.422  36.39   2017-06-13 15:00:00.000
A   0.0461028   32.2647927  S2  19.408  37.853  2017-06-13 15:00:00.000
```

it should't make like this, i need the resualt like what i said for each hour data value of Temprature, Pressure, Percipitation, Sky,......

Comment: IMO, Poor design without any normalization.

Comment: @PrabhatG it's because it do a bulk insert from a txt file into 8 table (8 metrological variables) i don't know why they design it like that but that's what it is any suggestion?

Comment: Try Creating Index on ID_Geo. This is will reduce the query execution time.

Comment: Firstly create clustered index on ID_Geo. Then go with simply joining 2 tables based on ID_geo. eg : `Select 
a.ID_geo, a.NAME,
a.Value as Temperature,
b.Value as Simboles,
a.Date
from
data_temprature a
inner join 
data_WeatherSimbol b
on
a.ID_geo = b.ID_geo`

Comment: @Debabrata good idea. on view or each 8 table?

Comment: @AriaR. on each 8 table

Comment: Can you post your executionplan, so we can see what is the problem. Create index on Date desc,ID_Geo include Value, might help.

Comment: @Peter i update the post

Comment: @AriaR. I see you've updated the post, but there is still not an execution plan. Also you forgot to put the date in your join.

Comment: @Peter sorry i forgot. i shared the link of execution plan in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just join on the geo and date:

```
select t.*, ws.simboles
from data_temperature t join
     data_WeatherSimbol ws
     on t.ID_geo = ws.ID_geo and t.date = ws.date;
```

Comment: the problem of this is that it will be super slow

Comment: Why would a `join` be "super slow"?

Comment: i guess because of to many joins is't better to make a view from these tables? or manage it with index cluster ?

Comment: @AriaR. . . . I don't know what your database structure is.  There is no reason to think that `JOIN`s will be "super slow".  Views are not going to help performance (in most databases, at least they don't make performance worse).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;With data_temprature(ID_geo,NAME,Value,[Date])
AS
(
SELECT  10005 , 'Madrid'   ,  32   , '2017-06-12 08:00' Union all
SELECT  10005 , 'Madrid'   ,  25   , '2017-06-12 09:00' Union all
SELECT  12701 , 'Paris'    ,  23   , '2017-06-12 08:00' Union all
SELECT  13006 , 'Tokyo'    ,  25   , '2017-06-12 11:00' Union all
SELECT  11132 , 'Sevilla'  ,  27   , '2017-06-12 16:00' Union all
SELECT  21333 , 'London'   ,  22   , '2017-06-12 17:00' 
)
,data_WeatherSimbol(ID_geo,NAME,Value,[Date])
AS
(
SELECT  10005 , 'Madrid'   ,  'A+'   , '2017-06-12 08:00' Union all
SELECT  10005 , 'Madrid'   ,  'A'   ,  '2017-06-12 09:00' Union all
SELECT  12701 , 'Paris'    ,  'A-'   , '2017-06-12 08:00' Union all
SELECT  13006 , 'Tokyo'    ,  'C-'   , '2017-06-12 11:00' Union all
SELECT  11132 , 'Sevilla'  ,  'I+'   , '2017-06-12 16:00' Union all
SELECT  21333 , 'London'   ,  'D-'   , '2017-06-12 17:00' 
)
SELECT ID_geo,
       NAME,
       Temperature,
       Symboles,
       [Date]  From 
(
SELECT t.ID_geo ,
        t.NAME ,
        t.Value AS Temperature,
        w.Value AS Symboles,t.[Date] ,
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t.Value,t.[Date] ORDER BY t.[Date]) AS Rno
 FROM data_temprature t
INNER join data_WeatherSimbol w
On t.ID_geo=w.ID_geo
)Dt 
WHERE Dt.Rno=1
ORDER BY ID_geo
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `[ID_geo]` nor `[Date]` seems to be unique enough to join, so:

1. Create an index on the both columns for all the tables like

   `create index IX_data_temprature on data_temprature ([ID_geo], [Date])`
2. Join all the tables by `[ID_geo]`, `[Date]`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the load of the query is caused by RID lookups.

RID lookups are used when the indexes don't cover the query (Sql has to lookup the values in the table because they are not included in the index) and the index is non-clustered.

You query may be faster if you used covered indexes, you probably did not include value in your index. More about including can be found in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns).

It may also help if you change your non-clustered index into a clustered index.